# Copy worksheet to multiple workbooks - formula references

Tags: excel, vba, copy, formulas

I have used the following Macro, that I found on another forum to copy one sheet into multiple other worksheets:

```
    Option Explicit
Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook

    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination woorkbook

    Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Folder containing the destination workbooks

    folder = "F:\temp\excel\"

    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls", vbNormal)
    While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Wend
 End Sub
```

The source worksheet, that I want to copy into the other destination worksheets has formulas (related to other worksheets in the source file). 
After running the macro, the formulas in the destination worksheet, still have references to the source worksheet instead of the destination worksheet.

How could I modify the macro in order to to adjust the references to the new workbook?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

You could just deleted the inserted references after you have copied the sheet. For example, if your source workbook is named "Source.xlsx":

```
Cells.Replace What:="=[Source.xlsx]", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart _
, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ 
ReplaceFormat:=False
```